# Select entries that have exactly specified associations in SQL

Tags: sql

If, for example, there is some entity that can have multiple tags, and associations are described using additional table `entity_tag` which holds `entity_id` and `tag_id`, how can I select all entities which have exactly some set of `tag_id`s?

Basically something like this:

```
select entity_id 
from entity_tag et 
where (select tag_id 
       from entity_tag
       where entity_id = et.entity_id) = (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find entities where entity_tag  contains all 3 tags for an entity, and possibly more.

```
select entity_id 
from entity_tag 
where tag_id in (1,2,3)
group by entity_id 
having count(distinct tag_id)=3
```

3 tags exactly

```
select entity_id
from entity_tag 
group by entity_id 
having count(distinct case when tag_id in (1,2,3) then tag_id else 0 end) = 3
and min(case when tag_id in (1,2,3) then tag_id else 0 end) > 0
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3ed56e7d00b0dbd4758a004418f58010)

Comment: Shouldn't your first piece of SQL finish `having count(distinct tag_id) >= 3`?

Comment: @Vérace, no because the `where` clause limits possible values to 3 items only. But the second query may need more check to exclude sets of values kind of (1,2,7) or (2,3,10) . Added it to the query

Comment: @Serg Is this actually true? I've just tried example like you mentioned in your comment and actually first query seems to get the job done. Because `tag_id` 7 is not `in (1,2,3)` and will not be selected, which means that `count(distinct tag_id)` will not be 3 and `entity_id` will not be selected. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @wdc , see the dbfiddle. The first query returns two `entity_id`s with all (1,2,3) [and  more] tags. The second query returns only one `entity_id` with exactly those tags and nothing more.  `entity_id` which misses at least one of tags (1,2,3) is ignored by both queries.