# Selecting all photos that contains specific people

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table, with two columns [photo,person]. I go through each photo, lets say photo one contains Ben and Harry, so I insert two rows.

My table now looks like this.

```
Photo, Person

1, Ben

1, Harry
```

I want to be able to select all the photos that contain Ben and Harry in the same picture(But not limited to just Ben and Harry, if others are in the picture, that's okay). I tried searching for sample statements, but can't get the wording for the query I want. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select entries that have exactly specified associations in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574017/select-entries-that-have-exactly-specified-associations-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by photo and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select photo
from tablename
group by photo
having sum(person in ('Ben', 'Harry')) = 2
```

or:

```
select photo
from tablename
where person in ('Ben', 'Harry') 
group by photo
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 Select distinct photo from your_table where person in ("Ben", "Harry")
```

`where person in ("Ben", "Harry")` - gets all rows where person is either Ben or Harry

`DISTINCT` - removes duplicate photos from results

UPDATE:

```
SELECT A.photo FROM your_table A WHERE A.person = "Ben" AND exists (SELECT 1 FROM your_table B where A.photo = B.photo AND A.person = "Harry")
```

Here I am selecting all rows with Ben and using a subquery to limit the results to rows with Harry as well.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I want to select the photos where both Ben and Harry are in the same picture.